# How to make form inputs and buttons avoid keyboard on mobile?

Tags: reactjs

In **React-Native**, there is a Component called `KeyboardAvoidingView`, but I could not find something similar for Reactjs. Is there a way to make sure that the keyboard does not cover the inputs and the Submit button, whenever a user is typing on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't want your keyboard to cover text inputs or Button in **Mobile Application** there is only on library as you mentioned [KeyboardAvoidingView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview) .
And if it is not working correctly then you can try this React-native [example](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-your-react-native-app-respond-gracefully-when-the-keyboard-pops-up-7442c1535580/)

But React is totally based on **Web** so there is no specific library in Reactjs to control mobile keyboard .